# Tecplot Span-Wise Loading Visualization

Tags: fluid-dynamics

all.

I have data from a CFD simulation for a wing, and I need to obtain a visualization of the span-wise load distribution. I'm attempting to do this using Tecplot. I've tried using 'slices' and 'vectors', but got stuck. Any ideas on how to do this? Any input from engineers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you manage to produce so far? Have you tried any of the numerous forums for ANSYS discussion?

Comment: I am not using an ANSYS product. In fact, I am not familiar with ANSYS, and did not know that it relates to my question.